# Use object name to return value of a specific property

Tags: c#, class, object, console.writeline

Is there any method that a object name return the specified property value like a variable. For example I have the following class

```
class Class1
{
    int valInt;
    double valDouble;
    string valString;
    public Class1(int intValue)
    {
        valInt = intValue;
    }

    public Class1(double doubleValue)
    {
        valDouble = doubleValue;
    }

    public Class1(string stringValue)
    {
        valString = stringValue;
    }        
}
```

So when I use its object like this

```
        List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();

        list.Add(new Class1(25));
        list.Add(new Class1(3.15));
        list.Add(new Class1("Name"));

        foreach (Class1 item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item); -> it outputs 25, 3.15, name
        }
```

Comment: why not just make a public method of your own that does that? It seems simple enough.

Comment: Override the `ToString` method.

Comment: But i want object to return int and double value also @CodyGray

Comment: e.g like class1 obj=new obj(25);    
int value= obj;

Comment: Its simple to use method and get value through property but i want more simple solution if one exists. @DPac

Comment: So you want [implicit conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk2z37d3.aspx)? There's nothing that will do this *automatically*, you're going to have to write code. But it isn't difficult, you are already passing the value to the ctor.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray you got my point. implicit conversion operators is the solution to my problem i think